# Batik 1.7 gives Headless mode exception : NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/java/awt/peer/headless/HeadlessToolkit

Tags: java, headless, batik

I am implementing Batik-1.7 with transcoder.so it is giving error that:

error: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gnu/java/awt/peer/headless/HeadlessToolkit

can anyone please suggest me how to use trancoder in headless mode...

thanks,

Comment: post the full stacktrace. The exception is caused by missing jars or incorrect class loading.

Comment: It is not missing JAR problem..as i have tested in my windows and *nix machines..it works fine..as i have uploaded same program in another linux machine it gives above error of headless mode..as there graphics devices are not available..i read through this forum:: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42408

Comment: What OS are you having trouble with? Did you install the relevant headless packages? E.g. http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/default-jre-headless

Comment: As i am giving uname -a command..i am receving below information..                                                                Linux localhost 2.6.27.45-crl #1 Wed May 16 13:47:09 IST 2012 i686 unknown

Comment: @ Asha Koshti :  Having the full stack trace posted would have helped to get better answer. You can give a display using VNC, typically used in build environments - not sure about production cases.

Comment: it is not about giving graphical display..we are developing for particular device..in that graphical display is not at all available..as it gives headless property as true..

Answer (score 0):

i was not able to solve the headless package problem because of JAMVM..
now i am converting the svg with librsvg..

thanks..